# How is the size of a fuction pointer always the same?

Tags: memory, rust, function-pointers

Playing around with Rust I discovered this:
[image: function pointer sizes in Rust]

How can the size of a function pointer be always the same? How do they know that the function pointer should point to a function with those specific arguments and return type then?

Comment: The size of a pointer (to *anything*) is always fixed and determined by the system, it0s just a memory address after all. It doesn't depends on the meaning of the object you're pointing to.

Comment: @Alejandro so how does the pointer know that the function should have that many arguments and that specific return type?

Comment: It doesn't at all! A pointer is just an address in memory, how do you use it depends solely on the program and how it uses it. The compiler does knows more about what each pointer means (as you declare its type) and will help validate things at compile-time. But once you've got your binary, no information at all exists on what the pointer actually means. Some languages even let to cast pointers to other types, and if you mix them up..... well.... bad things happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function pointer is always the same size because it's a pointer! Functions defined with `fn` are stored in static memory and are never moved around. A pointer is sufficient to reference them.

The arguments of the function are known at compile time, as part of the type. The type checker uses those to make sure that the function is being called correctly and to generate assembly instructions to actually call the function. At runtime, the `fn` pointer can be considered to be data, while the detailed information about the function arguments is encoded in the compiled instructions.